# Как показать сущности помеченные @Where(...)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, аннотации, role

Я работаю со spring MVC через hibernate. Моя БД mysql.
Есть сущность допустим USER у которого есть несколько полей в том числе и поле delete_date. Это поле я использую для soft delete. Поэтому над сущностью у меня стоит следующая аннотация:

```
@Where(clause = "delete_date IS NULL")
```

Таким образом я отображаю только не удаленных пользователей. Теперь появилась задача: Необходимо создать контроллер на спринге java, чтобы можно было смотреть всех пользователей админу. Пользователь админ имеет роль 'ADMIN'.

Можно ли как то отключить данный фильтр для пользователей с ролью админ?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге получилось сделать все что требовалось при помощи дополнительного метода в DAO:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM bookings", nativeQuery = true)
List<Booking> getFullBookingsList();
```